# ng-change does not work when selected items are changed

Tags: angularjs

I'm new to angular, I was trying to display cascading dropdown lists. Here is my html code

```
<div class="row" ng-controller="createCabsTicketController as tktCreatecabsCntrl">

    <select id="LocalCompanyIDForSearch" ng-change="getIXs()" ng-model="createCabsTicket.cabsCompanies.selected" name="LocalCompanyIDForSearch" class="form-control" style="width:100%;">
                <option value=" "> </option>
                <option ng-repeat="localCompany in createCabsTicket.cabsCompanies"
                        value="{{ localCompany.CompanyID }}">
                    {{ localCompany.LongDescription }}
                </option>
            </select>
    <select id="IXCname" name="IXCname" class="form-control" style="width:100%;">
                <option value=" "> </option>
                <option ng-repeat="ix in createCabsTicket.IXCarrierNames"
                        value="{{ ix.Interexchange }}">
                    {{ ix.Interexchange }}
                </option>
            </select>
```

And here is my js file contents

```
app.controller('createCabsTicketController',['$scope','$http',function($scope,$http){
    $scope.createCabsTicket = {
        cabsCompanies: [],
        IXCarrierNames: [],
        IXCarrierIds:[]
    };
    $http.get('http://localhost:52377/api/reference/companies/active', { cache: true }).success(function (data) {
        $scope.createCabsTicket.cabsCompanies = data;
    });
    $scope.getIXs = function (selectedItem) {
        var postData = { ActiveOnly: true, CompanyId: selectedItem, CarrierId: "", CarrierName: "", CarrierType: "" };
        $http.post('http://localhost:52377/api/reference/interexchanges', postData, { cache: true }).success(function (data) {
            $scope.createCabsTicket.IXCarrierNames = data;
        });
    }
}]);
```

The web services work and the parent list gets populated just fine. But the ng-change event doesn't get fired. I am not sure what did I do wrong. I have found similar posts but they were not quite helpful to solve my problem. Please help!!

Comment: You never pass in `selectedItem` from the view to the `getIXs` function - altho I don't think that's causing the issue.

Comment: When you say the ng-change event isn't fired, how are you checking this? IE if you set a breakpoint on "var postData ..." is it hit?

Comment: You should use `ng-options` - not an `<option>` tag with `ng-repeat`.

Comment: @tymeJV The data dats was not getting displayed when I use ng-options, so I used ng-repeat.

Comment: @Vlad274 I am using chrome debugger to check it. Also I have the webservice running locally, I can see that the post call is never hit.

Comment: Is this your full code? Do the <select> elements have any parents between them and the controller declaration?

Comment: the <select> element belongs to a form which is placed inside the div.Using the dev tools in chrome I was able to see that the controller gets called when I load the page, but not the function call.

Comment: `ng-options = "localCompany.CompanyID as localCompany.LongDescription for localCompany in createCabsTicket.cabsCompanies"`

Comment: @tymeJV Just tried, the ng-options was working had a typo before..any suggestions for the ng-change?

Comment: No idea.. it all looks right... try making a new function? Not sure.

Comment: @tymeJV okay. Thanks for your time. I'll post back if I can get it to work.

Comment: $http.post is an asynch event that will hit the call back after the digest cycle.  You will need to add $scope.$apply(); in each of the call backs where you alter your data

Comment: @JimFallin  The problem is that the function getIX() does not get called. I've include the statement in the call back, but still no result.

Comment: did you put a break point in the method to be sure?